# jQuery tablesorter plugin works in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer, google-chrome, tablesorter

I am trying use the jQuery table sorter plugin for a table that is generated using ASP.NET gridview.

For some maddening reason, it works fine in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome. It always seems to sort only on the first column even if you click on other columns.

I have uploaded the generated html (after stripping to the bare minimum while still keeping the ASP.NET ids etc, just in case they could the cause of the problem). Please tale a look at

http://www.reliacap.com/tsorter/tsorter.html

It is self contained except for tablesorter script and style sheet which are in the same folder.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I was not sure if I should paste the HTML here and clutter the screen...Should I do it anyway since the example web page may not be available after a few months to whoever reads this question?

Comment: Have you tried using "complex" text extraction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes it work for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('table[id$=GridView1]').tablesorter({
     textExtraction: 'complex'
   });
});
```

I think the `<span>` tags inside your table cells confuses the plugin if you don't explicitly tell it to do fancy content extraction.

Comment: ...this may actually explain a problem I was having with tablesorter in a project I was working on.